# how to retrieve xml node if it contains entity in xml node?

Tags: xslt

I have an xml file in this format

```
<xml>
<entity>&acces;</entity>
</xml>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of entity using `<xsl:value-of select="xml/entity">` but it's returning empty string. Any hint how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what your XML looks like?

It is missing the entity declaration or DTD reference that would define that entity. Your XML parser should throw an error, but may just be silently "skipping" it, so when you attempt to obtain the value, it is empty.